# javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated with rally api 2.2.1

Tags: rally

I am trying to integrate rally with java project using rally api version 2.2.1 but I am getting an exception:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated exception.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Show us some code you have tried. Use https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask in order to improve your question

Comment: Sounds like there's a self signed cert in there somewhere.  Are you using a proxy?  Are you using an on-prem instance of rally (not rally1.rallydev.com)?

Comment: I was able to solve it, The issue was with httpclient 4.2.5 and jdk 7 version compatibility. I enabled the debugging with JDK and all certificates were fine and i am not using proxy also. Finally with JDK 8 upgrade all issues solved. but this is weird and never thought it has something to do with Java version. anyways thanks much for your support.